# Showing a limit approaches infinity

Tags: calculus

I want to evaluate

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} t e^t $$

Intuitively, we see that $t e^t \to \infty$. But, how can we show it?

I would set $t = \frac{1}{x}$, then

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ e^{1/x} }{x} = ... $$

This does not help since we cant apply lhopitals rule. Is there another way to prove it diverges to $\infty$?

Comment: Not really your question, but it would be much more interesting to evaluate $$ \lim_{t \to \infty} t e^{-t} $$ because that is, unlike yours, an indeterminate form

Comment: Call me closed-minded if you like, but I think it is a shame for a 5k user to ask for such trivial questions. $e^t\geq 1+t$, what else do you need?

Comment: If you are OK with $$\lim_{t\to \infty}t=\infty$$
and you accept the $\log(t)$ to be strictly increasing monotonic and $\leq t$ everywhere. You can just look at

$$\log(te^t) =\log(t) + t$$

First term is positive everywhere and second gives the limit you seek and the unlogged expression follows by a squeeze argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that $e^t \to +\infty$ then clearly $te^t \to +\infty$. There is no indeterminate form here, so no need for l'Hôpital's rule:
$$(+\infty)\cdot(+\infty)=+\infty$$
Or by comparison: for $t>0$ you have $e^t > 1$ so then you also have $te^t>t$, hence...

Answer (score 2):

When $t > 0$ then $f(t) = t e^t > t e^0 = t$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, let $M > 0$.
Note that $te^{t} > e^{t}$ if $t > 1$; and $e^{t} > M$ if $t > \log M$.
So $te^{t} > M$ if $t > \max \{ 1, \log M \}$.
This shows that, for every $M > 0$ we have $te^{t} > M$ for large $t$;
i.e. $te^{t} \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$.